# wrought/wring for cloth vs iron

Tags: etymology, homonyms

Wrought iron is characterised by how it has been squashed/beaten into shape.

Also, one could wring water from a cloth by strong physical manipulations.

I assume these words have a common origin, but I don't think we say "the blacksmith is busy wringing iron" or "the cloth has been wrought to merely damp".

What's the story here? Why don't we say "wringing iron" or "a wrought cloth"?

Comment: They both arise from "worked", in the sense of "put effort in to change them to suit your needs". More details are available in their established etymologies; any good dictionary will provide those, but I personally find [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wrought&allowed_in_frame=0) most convenient.

Comment: @DanBron Only *wrought* is derived from the OE ancestor of *work*; *wring* is derived from a distinct OE verb. Both are derived from the same PIE root, but the nasalized version from which *wring* derives is held to have already been distinct in PIE.

Comment: By the way, any comparison to *wrought* should have been with *wrung*, not *wring* or *wringing*

Compared to *wringing* we should expect *wrighting* but later English seems to think *cartwright, millwright, playwright, shipwright, wainwright, wheelwright* and just plain *wright* should be *cart maker, mill worker, play maker, ship worker, wain maker, wheelworker* and the like, or just plain *worker*